# Why does "sum" of a list in python flatten it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have recently discovered an interesting feature in python

If you type:

```
y=[[1,2],[3,4]]
sum(y,[])
```

Output is: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Does anyone know why the sum of a series of lists with an empty list gives a flattened version of y (i.e: all of the sub-lists of y as a single list)?

I would have expected the output to be a concatenation:
`[1,2],[3,4],[]`

Thanks

Comment: If you do `[1, 2] + [3, 4]`, you also get `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.  Since `lists` are sequences, `+` treated as concatenation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions

Comment: Be careful, sum did flatten your list only because it was 2D! 
If you try this `sum([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]], [6, 7]], [])`, you'll see that it won't flatten it.

Comment: *Don't do this* - it is one of the least efficient ways you could flatten a list, taking quadratic time. A program may end up taking days instead of minutes simply because you did this.

Comment: @user2357112 that is good to know. I will avoid this in the future!

Answer (score 9):

`sum` iterates through an iterable and adds each element. It just so happens that with lists, addition is defined to be concatenation. By setting the second parameter (`start`) to `[]`, the function begins with a list and keeps adding on elements to it. Effectively:

```
sum([[1, 2], [3, 4]], []) == [] + [1, 2] + [3, 4]
```